# How can I grapple dozens of targets?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, grapple

What would be the cheapest most cost efficient way of grappling a *large* number of targets. (*I.e.* there are 100 people in front of me wanting to fight, I want to grapple as many as possible.) How can I achieve this wonderful goal of mine, using the resources available to a level 6-8 character?

This can't use class features, as I'll be playing a homebrew class based on [*luchadores*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucha_libre). All I want to do is grapple as many things as I possibly can. It's not a particularly creative goal, but it's my goal (lol). Spells (cast by another, since the *luchador* is not a caster), items, feats are all on the table.

Answer (score 13):

You can hire a mercenary (featuring a pair of arms and a willingness to grapple your enemies) for 2gp per day.  There's no practical limit to the number of targets you can grapple if you're willing to delegate and willing to pay.

Comment: Nice end-run. Have ten points.

Answer (score 6):

Within the rules, there's only one way to go about getting extra arms on your character: *Wish* for them and hope for a good result. You may want to buy your DM a pizza or something first.

That said, you do have some other options. The easiest one is to turn into something which has more arms. The *True Polymorph* and *Shapechange* spells will let you do this. Only *Shapechange* will allow you to use your class features while in your alternate form, though.

The other one is to talk to your DM about homebrewing a race with extra arms, or maybe a magic item that gives extra arms. Either way, it's entirely up to you and them to work out the details.

Comment: Food is often the way to a DM's heart